# Mercurial: "cannot follow nonexistent file" after hg log --follow

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I did `hg mv foo.txt foo2.txt`. Mercurial marked the file as being added instead of modified.

I did `hg log --follow foo2.txt` but got `abort: cannot follow nonexistent file: foo2.txt`.

I would expect the above command to work as expected by copying over the log from foo.txt to foo2.txt and mark the file as modified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2016-January/049281.html).

Comment: @AmiTavory I couldn't find any culprits in the ~/.hgrc file

Comment: Sorry. Good luck.

Comment: @aflp91 You should transform your comment in an answer, since it is correct :-)

Comment: Did you check @aflp91's answer? It is correct. Please verify that it works for you and accept it if it is the case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to commit the renaming first and then you could show revision history :

`hg commit -m "Renamed foo"`
`hg log --follow -v`